# Regular expression pattern matching in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

Pattern matching in Javascript

I want to make pattern which matches the string

```
{"ABC":["A1","X30","2","A2","X31","3","A3","X90","9"],"XYZ":["A1","X31","2","A3","X40","7"]}
```

I have used regex pattern

```
{("["A-Z0-9"]+":["[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"],)+}
```

but it doesn't match properly.

Every array length is multiple of 3 only and first & second element in pair of 3 consist of `[A-Z0-9]` only and third element consist of `[0-9]` only.

For example: `"A1","X30"` (first two element) & `"2"`(third element) similarly after 3 elements this pattern repeats `"A2","X31"` as first and second element and `"3"` as third element.

test pattern-1:

```
{"ABC":["A1","X30","2"],"XYZ":["A1","X31","2","A3","X40","7"]}
```

test pattern-2:

```
{"ABC":["A1","X30","2","A2","X31","3","A3","X90","9"],"XYZ":["A1","X31","2","A3","X40","7"]}
```

test pattern-3:

```
{"ABC":["A1","X30","2"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to optionally repeat the inner part with the 3 parts  again:

```
{"["A-Z0-9"]+":["[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"(?:,"[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+")*](?:,"["A-Z0-9"]+":["[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"(?:,"[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+")*])*}
```

The pattern in parts:

- `{` Match opening `{`
- `"["A-Z0-9"]+":["[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"` Match the part before the `:` followed by 3 parts after it consisting of 2 times `[A-Z0-9]` and only digits for the 3rd part
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,"[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `]` Match `]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,"["A-Z0-9"]+":["[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"` Match a again the part before the `:` and the 3 parts after it
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `,"[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"` Match a comma and repeat the first part again
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
  - `]` Match `]`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `}` Match closing `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RqQM0W/1)

Comment: {"ABC":["A1","X","2"]} It doesn't work on string like this because there should be a number followed by upper case letter in First and Second Element.

Comment: Then you can replace the `[A-Z0-9]+` parts with `[A-Z][0-9]+` or the other way around.

Comment: I have changed [A-Z0-9]+ to [A-Z]+[0-9]+ and it works !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

This is a correct pattern:

```
{("[A-Z0-9]+":\[("[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+"(,|(?=\])))+\](,|(?=})))+}
```

where `(,|(?=\]))` means "match a `,` or check that it is followed by a `]`".

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/S3bXNk/1).

Anyway, you should use a JSON parser if you want to be sure not to have unwanted behaviors.

Comment: {"ABC":["A1","X","2"]} It doesn't work on string like this because there should be a number followed by upper case letter in First and Second Element

Comment: Then use [`{("[A-Z0-9]+":\[("[A-Z][0-9]+","[A-Z][0-9]+","[0-9]+"(,|(?=\])))+\](,|(?=})))+}`](https://regex101.com/r/2kYdHk/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can add sub groups.

```
{("[A-Z0-9]+":\[("[A-Z0-9]+","[A-Z0-9]+","[0-9]+",?)+\],?)+}
```

https://regex101.com/r/OqjcVv/1